# TTL Remover on Cassandra Data

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I have a scenario where the application has inserted data into the Cassandra table with a (TTL) of 5 days.I also have (GC_GRACE_SECONDS) to 5 days so that tombstones will get evicted as soon as compaction kicks in.

Now, i have a scenario where for one table i need to keep data for 60 days. I have changed the application write to update the TTL to 60 days for the new Data. But I'm looking for a solution where i could change the TTL for existing data(which has 5 days to 60 Days).

I have tried Instaclustr/TTLRemover for some reason the code didn't work for us.
We are using Apache Cassandra 3.11.3.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide clarity on the parameters:

**default_time_to_live**: TTL (Time To Live) in seconds, where zero is disabled. The maximum configurable value is 630720000 (20 years). If the value is greater than zero, TTL is enabled for the entire table and an expiration timestamp is added to each column. A new TTL timestamp is calculated each time the data is updated and the row is removed after all the data expires.
Default value: 0 (disabled).

**gc_grace_seconds** : Seconds after data is marked with a tombstone (deletion marker) before it is eligible for garbage-collection. Default value: 864000 (10 days). The default value allows time for Cassandra to maximize consistency prior to deletion.
Note: Tombstoned records within the grace period are excluded from hints or batched mutations.

In your case you can update TTL and gc_grace_seconds to 60 days for new data to expire in 60 days time. But as your existing data is already marked with ttl as 5 days, it will not  be updated with new ttl and will be deleted in 5 days. As per my knowledge there is no way to update the ttl for existing data.

Answer (score 0):

We can set TTL with two ways 1) from query 2) On table.
Just update TTL on that table or re-insert the query with new TTL value.